# I would like to inquire about packaging an EXE file with PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, pyinstaller, caffe2

I would like to inquire about packaging an EXE file with PyTorch. Is it possible to execute the EXE file on another computer without the need to install Conda or PyTorch separately?

I have attempted to package my program into an EXE, and it runs successfully on another computer with a similar environment. However, my goal is to have the EXE file run directly on other computers without installing the same environment. Is this feasible?

this error info is from other computer,when I just use EXE file to run.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "torch__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
OSError: [WinError 126] 找不到指定的模組。 Error loading "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI224162\torch\lib\caffe2_nvrtc.dll" or one of its dependencies.
[25104] Failed to execute script 'predict' due to unhandled exception!
```